# How do I create a function to recommend a price in a neighborhood based on average price and overall satisfaction?

Tags: python-3.x

So this is my homework and I have no clue how to start. Below is a data sample from the larger data set.

Conditions: at least 1 review and an overall satisfaction score of 4 or more

```
data = [
    {
        'listing_id': '1133718',
        'host_id': '6219420',
        'city': 'Singapore',
        'neighborhood': 'MK03',
        'reviews': 9.0,
        'overall_satisfaction': 4.5,
        'accommodates': '12',
        'price': 74.0,
        'latitude': 1.293354,
        'longitude': 103.769226,
    },
    {
        'listing_id': '1196810',
        'host_id': '6236420',
        'city': 'Singapore',
        'neighborhood': 'MK11',
        'reviews': 5.0,
        'overall_satisfaction': 3.5,
        'accommodates': '11',
        'price': 84.0,
        'latitude': 1.34567,
        'longitude': 103.769226,
    }
    .
    .
    .
    ]
```

So the expected output will be something like this:

> price_recommender(data, 'neighborhood') =>  recommended price in that neighborhood

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you're supposed to iterate on the `data` list and filter out items that match your conditions. The simplest and mst obvious solution is a `for` loop:

```
for item in data:
    if <item_matches_conditions>:
        print("found item {}".format(item))
```

It's not clear from your "specifications" whether one should return all matching items, only the first one or if they should be sorted based on some "better fit" score, but if you want all matching items the best is to store them in another list.